# Can inheritance in OOP cause problems?

Tags: oop, computer-science

In `OOP` there is no way of removing the inherited elements such as a `method` or a `variable` from a super class. I am wondering is this a strenght or a weakness of the `OOP`? 
There is certainly a lot of benefits you get from this approach, but can this also cause any problems/issues such as security, performance etc?

Comment: If there is a need of hiding inherited methods maybe is because the inheritance is not the relation between objects. If class B inherits from class A means that B is also a instance of A. Think in a car (4 wheels and a chassis) and brands of cars, all products considered cars will have 4 wheels and a chassis, if not they are not cars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a language such as C++, SUPER methods/properties can be private meaning they are not inherited, and for best practice, variables in a super should all be private and accessed through publicly derived access methods anyway

Answer (score 0):

It can be both a strength and a weakness, depending on the way it is used. You're supposed to use inheritance to reuse a class's **behavior**, not its methods or variables. I could go on writing about this, but I think that this article explains it pretty well: http://rcardin.github.io/design/programming/oop/fp/2018/07/27/the-secret-life-of-objects-part-2.html

Comment: Thanks for the input @rcosteria. A class's behaviour comes from its elements (methods, variables etc.) doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. The only difference here is the way you think about your design. If you just think about reusing the lines of code themselves, you might end up having derived classes that inherit methods that make no sense for them to have access to. Of course, you could make said methods private on the base class, and it makes total sense in some cases. However, when this happens, you should evaluate your design again and try to understand if the relation between the base and the derived class makes sense. If you haven't already, check the SOLID principles (especially the Liskov substitution principle).